# How to change the default ctrl + w to change navigate between panes and windows in NERdtree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to change the shortcuts in NERDTREE to use the navigation.

For example:
the default to move to the left window is 
`Ctrl`+`w` + `h`
and I want to use the letter `l` instead of `w` so the functionality will be `Ctrl` + `l`  +`h`.

Comment: something along the lines of `nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: it did work thanks!